# Url works when pinging but causes UriFormatException

Tags: c#, uri

I have a mail server I'm trying to connect to with exchange web services. If I ping the server, it works, but it gets a `UriFormatException` when provided in code.

**Urls that work in command prompt but fail in c#**

- `myserver.mydomain.com`
- `myserver`
- `192.168.100.1` (my server's ip)

**Urls that can be parsed into URIs but fail to be pinged**

- `http://myserver.mydomain.com`
- `http://192.168.100.1`

I also tried adding `\\` to the beginning but had no luck.

We do have a bit of a weird setup with connecting to our domain when on-network that I believe is what is causing `http://myserver.mydomain.com` to fail in ping. How can I turn the base url (without the http://) into a string that will be valid for a c# `Uri`?

Code:

```
var serverUrl = "myserver.mydomain.com"; //base string I'd like to use
_exchange.Url = new Uri(serverUrl); //causes UriFormatException:  Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
```

Comment: You do not pass a URI to the 'ping' command, you pass either a CNAME or an IP address, or something else that in the end resolves to an IP address. A URI needs to include the protocol. So the things you are listing are not the same and they are not intended to be the same. What is it you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: [MSDN Ping Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To consturct Uri from host name use `UriBuilder`:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder();
builder.Host = "myserver.mydomain.com"; 
var uri = builder.Uri;
```

Note that what you call "uri" (myserver.mydomain.com) is actually "host name" or "DNS name" which is what get resolved to IP and than used to Ping. "http://myserver.mydomain.com" is absolute Uri for particular protocol (HTTP).

Comment: this helps, but the full uri ends up becoming `http://myserver.mydomain.com`, which fails to connect, as the ping did. I suppose this is just an issue with how our server is set up on our local intranet

Comment: so if I call `ping myserver.mydomain.com` and it succeeds, but `ping http://myserver.mydomain.com` it fails, what url is ping parsing from the host name that is working in the first case?

Comment: @DLeh "ping http://myserver.mydomain.com it fails" because it is not how you call `ping` - you need to pass just IP/host name to ping... It is hard to see why you C# code fails without any samples.

Comment: i mean if i ping in a command prompt. without the `http://` it *succeeds*, with it fails

Comment: @DLeh I'm not sure what your question is - "why ping does not work when I pass random arguments to it"? "ping my name is DLeh" will fail too - does it mean anything?

Comment: what are you talking about? if i ping `myserver` it works, if i ping `http://myserver` it fails. Those are hardly random arguments.  You're getting my words switched. So, if pinging `myserver` works, then what url is ping ultimately using if it's transforming it from a hostname into a url?

Comment: @DLeh I've never seen Uri for [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol), sorry I don't know what scheme or port one would use to construct absolute Uri for ping request. Also I've never seen ping client that would take url, so it generally not a problem.